# Object required Error showing value of object?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am working on a legacy classic asp application where I am trying to pull the value of a new id being inserted in to the database.

```
Set LastCompany2= Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
LastCompany2.ActiveConnection = objConn
LastCompany2.CommandType = 1
LastCompany2.CommandTimeout = 0
LastCompany2.Prepared = true
LastCompany2.CommandText = MM_editQuery
Set ScopeID = LastCompany2.Execute()
If ScopeID.EOF Then
   Company_No2 = 0
Else
   Company_No2 = cstr(ScopeID(0).value)
end if
```

however when running the application I get the error message on the line

```
Company_No2 = cstr(ScopeID(0).value)
```

stating

> Object required: '3333380'

or whatever the id of the inserted record was.

I can't figure out why it thinks the object is missing but is then displaying the value of said object

Comment: Can you show the query you are using for the `CommandText`?

Comment: Unfortunitly I can only get a overview of the querry as it has a lot of fileds in it but i can say the querry is working without issue and the record is being created and the id of that record is being displayed in the error message. Here is the query "SET NOCOUNT ON; insert into " & MM_editTable & " (" & MM_tableValues & ") values (" & MM_dbValues & "); SET NOCOUNT OFF; Select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as ID;"

Comment: Ideally, you should [edit] the question rather than post code in the comments.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you did to fix the issue, did you have `ScopeID` defined elsewhere for example? Trying to understand what about the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41850792/692942) solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a scoping issue.

Please make sure

```
Dim ScopeID
```

is declared.

Comment: Can you elaborate, what about the code made it a *"scoping issue"*? You suggesting there was another `ScopeID` in a different scope?